# What's the most common term in the (software) industry for "to debug" or "debugging"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Google suggests **depurar**, but that sounds a bit rigid and technical, almost clinical to me.

Are there other alternatives which are in common/colloquial use in the industry?

[One of the answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2794) for [***Translation of “bug” to Spanish***](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/translation-of-bug-to-spanish) claims that *pulga* is used in Costa Rica for bug. I guess ***despulgar*** would work in this context and doesn't suffer from the (perceived) stiffness of *depurar* (in fact, it sounds way cooler, by several orders of magnitude), but would it be understood?

Comment: Depurar is the most used term Source - I'm a Mexican software developer

Comment: I haven't seen any other word apart from "depurar" used for "to debug", but indeed "despulgar el código" sounds much funnier. Next time I have the chance to use it I'll try and see if others understand what I'm saying. :-D

Comment: we can consider the term clinical and maybe chemical, as this is a a word for: for clear, purification, purge, refine.

Comment: @Charlie - for historical accuracy -- perhaps *desmariposear*?  (When you're trying to have fun with coworkers.) https://labcoatlucy.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/first_bug.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard the following words in spanish, in order of frecuency:

Debuguear (debug spanglish). Voy a *debuguear* el software
Depurar (debug). Voy a *depurar* el software
Corregir (mend). Voy a *corregir* el software - It means a major problem
Purgar (purge). Voy a *purgar* el software - It means minor problems
Arreglar (fix). Voy a *arreglar* el software - It means a major problem
Pulir (polish). Voy a *pulir* el software - It means minor problems

Forget the word *despulgar*, somebody might believe you're talking of a dog instead of a software.

Source: Chile

Comment: Do you mean *debuguear*?

Comment: Fixed the spanglish. Thanks @aparente001.

Comment: I am from Spain and I've hears the same terms. Debugear is the one most used.